Firefox Kiosk does not appear when I log in but does when I start it manually from the GNOME x-terminal
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (on a Dell Optiplex 3000) with minimal installation.
I downloaded Firefox 125, removed the SNAP Firefox and installed this Firefox with no issue.
I can run "firefox --kiosk" and Firefox runs in kiosk mode with no issue.
I have made some changes in the "about:config" part of Firefox.
I have also made some changes to the Ubuntu keyboard shortcut list.
There is only one user created on this system and I have configured Ubuntu to login this user automatically upon reboot.
However, if I setup Firefox --kiosk to start automatically (I use the gnome-session-properties application to achieve this) and then reboot, Firefox does run, but it does not appear on the screen.
If I enter the "switch windows" keyboard shortcut (ALT-TAB), then the Firefox kiosk does appear.
So, is this something I can fix by changing the Firefox configuration, or is it an Ubuntu configuration change.
If so, can anyone tell me what I should do, or have an idea how to debug this?

Yes, I am starting up Firefox with the Startup Applications.  It's definitely running, it's just not displaying the kiosk initially and even if I wait the kiosk page does not appear.

I tried to replicate your problem in Ubuntu 24.04. I got a black screen until I refreshed it using the Super (Windows) key. It seems like a display (gnome?) problem rather than Firefox problem.
